# Javascript Echo Result in PHP

Tags: javascript, echo

Ok so I have some Javascript code that I'm wanting to echo.

Here is the Code im wanting to echo, I'm wanting it to basically print out the response from the generated "hospital" and "scramble" I've got this far just can't echo the result in PHP.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
 function hospital() {
  var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var string_length = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3000 - 256 + 1)) + 256;
  var prngstring = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
   var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
   prngstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
  }
  document.theform.hospital.value += prngstring;
 }

 function catchme() {
     var rounds = 812;
        var scramble = "lbwnaoJJgJbQCc1zxfiQugycOhboPrdbciAVBaBeqnzXzhztbPddaBWzNjcrafefibAcnJohbDQDbuaueudckuGvAuccEhPmehbjZdaecgAMphcPAeabFvxsGwteWS";

        for (var i = 0; i <= rounds; i++) {
            scramble = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(scramble)).toUpperCase();
        }
        document.theform.waste.value += scramble;
        hospital();
    }
-->
</script>
```

Would appreciate and support.

Answer (score 1):

There is no call to **catchme** function. You need to call **catchme** function so the following statements work.

- document.theform.waste.value += scramble;
- document.theform.hospital.value += prngstring;

Make catchme a self invoked function.

```
(function catchme() {
     var rounds = 812;
        var scramble = "lbwnaoJJgJbQCc1zxfiQugycOhboPrdbciAVBaBeqnzXzhztbPddaBWzNjcrafefibAcnJohbDQDbuaueudckuGvAuccEhPmehbjZdaecgAMphcPAeabFvxsGwteWS";

        for (var i = 0; i <= rounds; i++) {
            scramble = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(scramble)).toUpperCase();
        }
        document.theform.waste.value += scramble;
        hospital();
    })();
```

Comment: Sorry to be so dumb as its so late but how would I do that?

Comment: use **catchme()**  just as you did with **hospital()**. You can wrap catchme in a self invoked function

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for means of printing javascript code using php. You could do a straight echo "[all of your js goes here]" but this is clunky and will require a lot of escape characters. If you aren't familiar with the concept of escape characters, if I want to include a double quote in a string, I might erroneously write something like this:

```
$var = "Foo"Bar";
```

This will cause problems because the interpreter will see

```
$var = ["Foo"][Bar]["....]....
```

Where the last bit is all of the text in the php file until the next double quote. Then, it will parse the text after that double quote, which presumably should have been parsed as a string, as code until the closing quote, where it will start parsing your code as a string, etc. etc. So we use the escape character (typically ) to denote when we're using special characters in a string like so:

$var = "Foo\"Bar";

This is time consuming and hard to read if you can avoid it, which you can.

You can use multiple pairs of php tags () in a single php document. Anything written outside of a set of php tags will be printed out, so you could simply close the tag, print out your code, and then open another php tag, if necessary.

See this article for other helpful tips regarding echoing out large blocks of text: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: What I've found is best for me is a [NOWDOC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) or [HEREDOC](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) then an `echo` as the JavaScript can be pasted in as-is without worrying about having to escape all the quotes.